# How could I save a file with size 1gb into mysql?

Tags: mysql, blob

I have some problem when saving a big file into database:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter of prepared statement which is set through mysql_send_long_data() is longer than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

I dont want to case the value of 'max_allowed_packet', do we have solvtion to use java code to save it. This is my feature's requirment.
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

```
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:1026/vistapoint_99_99_99", "root", "root");
        PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement("insert into appliancedebugfilechunk (file_id, chunk_size, file_chunk, seq_number) values(?,?,?,?)");
        File file = new File("D:\\Tool\\ideaIU-14.0.1.exe"); //278MB

        prep.setInt(1, 3);
        prep.setLong(2, file.length());
        prep.setInt(4, 10);

        prep.setBinaryStream(3, new FileInputStream(file), file.length());
        prep.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Does query 'SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824' works? It change mysql config max_allowed_packet to 1GB. But, you have to reconnect to mysql server before uploading blob file

Comment: yes it works, but Are there any other ways instead of increasing the 'max_allowed_packet', Could  we streaming huge file , I supposed that mysql would read the file by chunks and insert each. I still dont know how could handle using this way.

Comment: usually you will save the file somewhere outside DB and save only the path in db.

Comment: Yes there are couples of  way could fix this issue. But my current requirement is I must save a large file into db. Mysql official document have not mentioned this. So I think It is impposible to save huge files with MYSQL IF we dont split it into small chunks RIGHT?